# Заменить средствами javascript одни теги на другие

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На странице есть теги вида

```
[indie][/indie]
[futurama][/futurama]
```

Нужно средствами javascript (jquery) найти подобные теги и заменить для каждого на html теги:

```
[indie]содержимое[/indie] => <span style=" font-family: 'Indie', cursive">содержимое</span>
[futurama]содержимое[/futurama] => <span style=" font-family: 'Futurama', sans-serif">содержимое</span>
```

Comment: Это в школе сейчас такие задачки по информатике?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример, результат в выводится в консоль

```js
var search = new Array(
  "\\[indie]?(.*?)\\[/indie]", 
  "\\[futurama]?(.*?)\\[/futurama]"
);

var replaceTo = new Array(
  '<span style="font-family: \'Indie\', cursive">$1</span>', 
  '<span style="font-family: \'Futurama\', sans-serif">$1</span>'
);

var str = '[indie]Indie text[/indie][futurama]Futurama text[/futurama]';

console.log('Было: ', str);
for (i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
  str = str.replace(new RegExp(search[i], 'g'), replaceTo[i]);
}

console.log('Стало: ', str);
```

Comment: А как это работает с div'ами? Если div с классом .post-content, в нём могут быть и таблицы, и p, и любые другие html теги. Если я пытаюсь заменить str на селектор, jquery выдаёт ошибки $('...').replace is not a functon.

Comment: @morganchees `.replace` работает со строками. `$('')` - jQuery объект, а не строка. Ты можешь взять `$('.post-content').html()` - выдаст строку со всем что находится в блоке `.post-content`.

Comment: спасибо, работает :)